# How many shipping addresses may be selected for an order during the checkout process?

Tags: magento2, checkout

```
A. One shipping address per line item is possible 
B. Only one shipping address per order is possible 
C. One shipping addresses per unit of quantity is possible 
D. One shipping address per product type is possible
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one shipping address per order is possible

Magento creates separate order for each shipping address during multi shipping checkout

Answer (score 0):

Only one shipping address is allowed in checkout.
please refer to magento 2 dev docs [here](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/checkout-step1-shipping.html#ship-to-a-different-address)!

but if you wish to enable multiple address shipping then you have to enable multi shipping option from back office (this option is allowed to registered users only)
to enable please refer to magento 2 dev docs [here](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-multiaddress.html)!

> In all the cases it will be only one order created.